# てもいいですか　vs. causative verb + もらってもいいですか

Tags: grammar

> 電話を**使わせて**もらってもいいですか。

I know that *causative verb form + てもらう* means to let somebody do something. And てもいいですか　is for asking for permission. But I don't quite understand the use of these 2 constructions together.

If I wanted to ask someone to let me use their phone, I would possibly say:

> 電話を使ってもいいですか。

How are the meanings of the two sentences different? Is "電話を使わせてもらってもいいですか" just more polite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

てもいいです - May I do(To Grant Permission)

causative form + もらってもいいです - Would you Please let me do(To seek permission)

Answer (score 2):

> 電話を使ってもいいですか。

literally means

> Is it ok for me to use the phone?

And

> 電話を使わせて貰ってもいいですか。

literally means

> Is it ok for me to be let to use the phone by you?

The latter one sounds more polite.